# WHERE AND condition in waterline mysql

Tags: mysql, waterline

I wrote this query in waterline.

```
s_course.findOne()
    .where({class:req.body.class})
    .where({teacher:req.body.teacher})
    .where({subject:req.body.subject})
    .exec(function(err,model){});
```

And I want all conditions to be true.if any of condition doesn't met query should return empty result but this query returns result even only one condition is met.

In short.this query behaves as **WHERE condition1 OR condition2** while i need **where condition1 AND condition2**.

**NOTE:** I don't want to use *.query()* method for this because of getting advantage of .populate method.